# Using the package HiddenMarkov with customized probability distribution of observables

Tags: r, probability, customization

How to define a customized probability distribution in a "R-standard way"? I know my cumulative distribution function(cdf) and random sampling function(rsf), say *pnewdist* and *rnewdist*. It is needed to define a probability distribution in R like it is done in the standard R case, viz, normal distribution where *rnorm* or *pnorm* are the *rsf* and *cdf* respectively. So, how to define my distribution *newdist* and link its *cdf* and *rsf* with *pnewdist* and *rnewdist*?

Ideally for using the *rnewdist* or *pnewdist* I dont need to do so but I want to use the R package HiddenMarkov with customized/user defined probability distribution for the observables instead of the available distributions in R(like normal or poisson etc.) so that in the command *dthmm*, I can use *distn=newdist*.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ecdf` uses a user-defined distribution to give you a function based on that distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I still doubt if it can resolve the issue. ecdf is used for empirical distribution construction but I need to include the parameters of the distribution, which are the parameters of the observable distribution in the HMM as well, as argument in the rnewdist and pnewdist,  and these parameters are to be estimated via EM algorithm.   Anyway, later I found that the package distr has some facilities towards that which I shall explore in detail.